# Cleaning up an utterance using multiple regex substitutions

Tags: python, regex, formatting

I need to use regex for some stuff (mentioned in code comments) and wrote the following code, which works perfectly fine for my need, but I wanted to know if there was a way to improve this code?

Am I using re.compile correctly in this case?

```
import re

def regex(utterance):

    utterance = utterance.lower()

    # Replacing non ASCII characters with space
    message_ascii = re.compile(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+')
    message_ascii = message_ascii.sub(r' ', utterance)

    # If comma after number, replace comma with space
    message_comma_no = re.compile(r'(?<=[0-9]),')
    message_comma_no = message_comma_no.sub(r' ',message_ascii)

    # If comma after words, add space before and after
    message_comma_word = re.compile(r'(?<=[a-z]),')
    message_comma_word = message_comma_word.sub(r' , ',message_comma_no)

    # If "Dot and space" after word or number put space before and after
    message_dot = re.compile(r'(?<=[a-z0-9])[.] ')
    message_dot = message_dot.sub(r' . ',message_comma_word)

    # If any other punctuation found after word or number put space before and after
    message_punct = re.compile(r"(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=[?;!()'\"])|(?<=[?;!()'\"])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])")
    message_punct = message_punct.sub(r' ', message_dot)

    # Remove Excess whitespaces
    message = ' '.join(message_punct.split())

    return message
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If you use a regular expression once, you don't get any performance improvement from compiling it. You could just use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.sub) directly.
2. If a string doesn't contain any special characters, there's no point in using a raw literal.
   `r' '` could be just `' '`.
3. Using the same variable to represent different things is a bad practice. It confuses the people who read your code. It's not a good idea to do things like:

   ```
   message_ascii = re.compile(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+')
   message_ascii = message_ascii.sub(r' ', utterance)
   ```

   because the same variable holds a compiled regex in the first line and it's reassigned to a string later on.

If you call this function multiple times and want to benefit from pre-compiled regular expressions, you could create a new class that compiles the expressions in its constructor and reuses them:

```
class TextProcessor:

    def __init__(self):
        # Initializes regular expressions here
        self.ascii_regex = re.compile(...)
        # Other expressions go here

    def process_text(self, text):
        ascii_text = self.ascii_regex.sub(' ', text)
        # The rest of the substitions go here
```

Comment: thanks, regarding point 1 this function will be called again and again, will it be right to use re.compile in such a case or should I just use re.sub?

Comment: @InheritedGeek You recompile it every time the function is called, anyway. If you compile it once (say, in an object constructor) and then used the existing compiled object in a method every time it's called, it can make your code faster.

Comment: @InheritedGeek Caching might also help you out here, see the note at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile (no need to use re.compile for this though)

Answer (score 2):

I would create an list with regex_pattern and the iterate over it like this.

```
import re

def regex(utterance):

    utterance = utterance.lower()

    regex_pattern = ["[^\x00-\x7F]+", "(?<=[0-9]),", "..."]

    for pattern in regex_pattern:
        message = re.compile.(pattern)
        msg = message.sub(" ", utterance)

       ...

    return message
```

Do you know what i mean? But if you want to replace also with other pattern i would create an dictionary like this:

```
regex_dict = {'[^\x00-\x7F]+': ' ', '(?<=[a-z]),': ' , '}
```

and then iterate over the regex_dict:

```
import re

def regex(utterance):

    utterance = utterance.lower()

    regex_dict = {'[^\x00-\x7F]+': ' ', '(?<=[a-z]),': ' , '}

    for key in regex_dict:
        message = re.compile(key)
        msg = message.sub(regex_dict[key], utterance)
        ...
    ...
```

I would be helpfull for me to test it for 100% if I had some examples for **utterance**.
Thanks

Comment: Here you will be iterating over "utterance" ie initial string each time, while I want to iterate over the updated string each time.